# how to use pagedown with rails 4?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, pagedown

I want to be able to post comments that include code without need for special formatting like on stackoverflow. I found that stackoverflow uses **PageDown**.

My question is: how to add **PageDown** from scratch to Rails application (step-by-step)?

Thanks

Comment: As always, there's a gem for that. https://github.com/rh/pagedown-rails

Comment: Thanks @AFaderDarkly, I found that before your comment but I didn't know how to implement it. Already done.